# Wrapping Figure within multicolumn text

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I got the problem that my image is not positioned correctly within the first text column.
I only want that the image is not overlapped with some text.
How to wrap the text around the image correctly to see a very clear image with text above and below the image?

[image]

```
\section{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
% Some text blocks
\begin{wrapfigure}[l]{1\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/presentation001/test.jpg}
\caption{blabla}
\end{wrapfigure}
% Some text blocks
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you get any error messages? The ``wrapfigure`` environment from ``wrapfig`` takes two _mandatory_ arguments; you should write ``{l}`` instead of ``[l]``. The optional argument is meant to specify the number of lines that the figure should span vertically. Maybe your compiler understood this as if the figure should span 0 lines. However, I don't think ``wrapfigure`` works well in two-column environments.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get any error messages. I was using wrapfigures like descriped from this link: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns.

I replaces [1] to {1}, but the text ist strangely overlapping, like 20 linebreaks, but the textpart is still floating over the image. :(

Comment: it isn't clear what your intention is `wrapfigure` is intended for a cutout where a paragraph wraps around the side and below the image, but you have specified the full `\linewidth` as the image width, which can't possibly work.

Comment: What should I do instead? What can I use instead of \linewidth?

Comment: What to do depends on how wide your image should be. If you want your image to be as wide as one of the columns, just use a regular figure environment.

Comment: After I inserted the figure with \begin{figure}[H] the text was not overlapping the figure and I still have a clear text flow. :)